# Having trouble installing atheme

Tags: irc

I'm trying to set up an IRC server using charbdyis and atheme. Charbdyis installed just fine, but I ran into an error while trying to run `$ make install` on atheme. It runs and I get the error:

`CompileModule: http.so
Install: http.so
/usr/bin/install: ‘http.so’ and ‘/home/nick/atheme/modules/api/http.so’ are the same file
make[2]: *** [install] Error 1
make[1]: *** [install] Error 2
make: *** [install] Error 2`

I've tried googling for this problem, but it seems my Google-fu isn't strong enough. Any help or suggestion will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

you need to set a different install target to the build location.

When running configure, you can specify --prefix which specifies the install location to place atheme to when running 'make install'.

The same goes for most programs built using autotools.

It is also recommended that you set the prefix to a location within your home directory and run atheme as an unprivileged user, as this is a more secure configuration and root privileges are not required for irc services.

There is more information on ./configure --prefix in the following answered question: [Linux configure/make, --prefix?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8902698/linux-configure-make-prefix)