# Configuring install path: prefix=[PREFIX] not fully understood

Tags: c++, path, ffmpeg, set, prefix

I think this is simply a general c++ question:

I'm attempting to compile a local version of ffmpeg on Linux Fedora using the gnu c++ compiler. I have source code in a bunch of folders under:

```
~/<username>/Downloads/Code/ffmpeg_sources/
```

which is where I'm attempting to set the config flags to install the build to a target not under this tree but at a root level directory with local shared libraries:

```
/usr/local/
```

There is this following section near the beginning of the configuration file:

```
Standard options:

 --prefix=PREFIX          install in PREFIX []
 --bindir=DIR             install binaries in DIR [PREFIX/bin]
 --datadir=DIR            install data files in DIR [PREFIX/share/ffmpeg]
 --docdir=DIR             install documentation in DIR [PREFIX/share/doc/ffmpeg]
 --libdir=DIR             install libs in DIR [PREFIX/lib]
 --shlibdir=DIR           install shared libs in DIR [PREFIX/lib]
 --incdir=DIR             install includes in DIR [PREFIX/include]
 --mandir=DIR             install man page in DIR [PREFIX/share/man]
 --enable-rpath           use rpath to allow installing libraries in paths
                          not part of the dynamic linker search path
```

I may have completely misunderstood this, but I thought that setting a value like

```
--prefix=/usr/local
```

or

```
--prefix=[/usr/local]
```

might work, but it appears not to, as once the ./config, make&&make install is complete, it has done a bunch of stuff but there's nothing installed at the target. There are a LOT of new executable files built in the source directory, so presumably the build is working but I'm simply specifying the paths incorrectly? A part of the same problem is that it's unclear whether, once I've set the

```
--prefix=[PREFIX]
```

correctly, I need to set all of the further

```
--datadir, --libdir
```

etc. or whether the first --prefix value is enough?

What is the above configuration syntax trying to show me?

Comment: Related, see [Linux configure/make, --prefix?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8902698/608639)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It should be the first one `--prefix=/usr/local` but to install files in that location you need *root* privileges. So you need to either change to the *root* account `su` or use `sudo` if you are a `sudo user` aka `sudo make install`. Only do that for the *install* phase, don't build like that.

Also `/usr/local` is usually the *default* install location so you don't usually need to specify that. Normally you only use `--prefix` to install into a different location like `--prefix=/opt` or your *home* folders: `--prefix=$HOME/3rdparty`.

Incidentally, if you install into your *home* folder you won't need *root* privileges.

Comment: oh! thanks for this :0)

I don't particularly mind where the local build goes. I'm doing it in order to compile Audacity against those specific ffmep libs. I read/was told that Audacity would look for it at /usr/local... presumably then this is the default for most things?

Will try again with the make. Thanks again :0)

Answer (score 0):

In my situation, `./configure` end up with warning/error, so `--prefix=` works with the default location (`/usr/local`). After I sorted out the warning/error, it worked as expected.