# How to specify the location in ./configure or make when building package from source?

Tags: linux, installation, package, autotools

Suppose I want to install a package under /opt, which of the three should be appended with "prefix"? I read a few materials and still am very confused. Thank you.

In which command(s) should I add the location?

`./configure prefix=/opt

make prefix=/opt

make prefix=/opt install`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Linux configure/make, --prefix?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8902698/608639) Also see questions like [Configuring install path: prefix=\[PREFIX\] not fully understood](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36998572/608639) and [What does --prefix do exactly when used in ./configure?](https://askubuntu.com/q/891835).

Comment: The command is `./configure --prefix=/opt/` . ... I.e. you are missing the two hyphens before prefix. ... See `./configure --help`

Answer (score 0):

An Autotools-based build system affords you two main alternatives: you may specify the installation prefix (and other installation locations) either at configuration time or at build time.

**To specify at configuration time**, you use the `--prefix` option to the `configure` script, as `./configure --help` will describe to you. For example,

```
./configure --prefix=/opt/mypackage
```

Typically, one then proceeds with unadorned

```
make
sudo make install
```

---

**To specify at build time**, you configure without the `--prefix` option, maybe simply

```
./configure
```

then you specify the prefix via the corresponding `make` *variable*.  It might in some cases suffice to specify it only to `make install`, but in others you need to specify it to both `make` runs, so it is wisest to adopt that as a general rule:

```
make prefix=/opt/mypackage
sudo make install prefix=/opt/mypackage
```

---

I note also that nothing should be installed directly in `/opt` -- that is, `/opt/bin`, `/opt/lib`, *etc*.  It ought instead to be installed in per-package subdirectories of `/opt`, possibly even grouped under provider-associated subdirectories.